# How do I add icons to a second Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, appcompat-v7-toolbar

I have more than one appcompat.v7 Toolbar in my layout.

Given this is the case the solution of "main" toolbars - `setSupportActionBar()` and then use the hooks in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` - isn't what I'm looking for.

The only way I've found so far is to cheat and put the Toolbar in a horizontal LinearLayout and "fake" action bar icons with ImageViews. There has to be a real way to do this but with the solution to "main" toolbars saturating searches I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to inflate a menu in your Toolbar:

```
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_detail);
```

Then you can use it to attach a listener:

```
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    //your code
                }    
            }
});
```